# List indexing Iteration Error

Tags: python

I am completely new to programming. I am trying to make a game in which I have a list of lists that works as a board on which players play 'GO'. A Japanese game in which a player takes spaces in the board, if the space becomes surrounded by two enemy spaces, then the other player takes that space. I represent it with 'R' and 'O' that simulates the players pieces.

The problem here is when I try to make the algorithm that replaces a players piece with the other one's by indexing horizontally, the code so far is as follows:

```
R = "R"
O = "O"
matrix = [[[" "] for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

def doBoard():
    for i in matrix:
        print "\n%r" % i 

def pickR():
    print "Select the column and row you want to take: \n"
    column = int(raw_input("Column: > "))
    row = int(raw_input("Row: > "))
    matrix[column][row] = "R"

def pick0():
    print "Select the column and row you want to take: \n"
    column = int(raw_input("Column: > "))
    row = int(raw_input("Row: > "))
    matrix[column][row] = "O"

def selector():
    for i in matrix:
        for j in i:
            if j == "R" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "R"
            if j == "O" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "O"
```

In the last line I get error

> Cannot concatenate 'int' and 'str' elements.

I get that what is happening here is that I am getting the string located in index j, and trying to add 2 to it, but I want to get the index j plus two more spaces, or two indexes forward. I have searched other questions here and can't get around it, how do I do this?

Comment: please post the error traceback.

Comment: if j == "R" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
TypeError: Cannot concatenate 'int' and 'str' objects

Comment: in the line below that, you're adding `j`, a string, to 1, an int.

Comment: I know, as I said in the last paragraph. I would like to know how to get the code so that I get the index plus one index forward, instead of the index plus and int.

Comment: what type are you thinking the index should be?

Comment: @andre see my answer , i guess it will do what you are trying to do as I have taken j as an integer and not a matrix element.

Answer (score -1):

```
def selector():
    for i in matrix:
        for j in i:
            if j == "R" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "R"
            if j == "O" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "O"
```

In your code `j` is an element of a matrix. So when you write `matrix[j+2]` j will not be an integer and concatenating it with 2 will give the following error:

```
Cannot concatenate 'int' and 'str' elements.
```

This should work for you I guess!

```
def selector():
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix)):    
            if matrix[j] == "R" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "R"
            if matrix[j] == "O" and matrix[j+2] == "R":
                matrix[j+1] = "O"
```

Here j is an integer and can be used to as an index.

Comment: When I tried your code I got
`TypeError: list indexes must be integers, not list`
 did I do something wrong?

Comment: @andre forgot to give the loop to j in for loop.